# PDF of selected questions asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to get "printout" on a single PDF file of selected questions and selected answers? This is for convenient reference. Wikipedia has a feature which allows users to compile topics into a "booklet". If this feature doesn't exist, it would a good idea to include it if possible.

Comment: Ironically, there's someone doing this and selling them as kindle books.  There should be a question about that here or over on [meta.so]

Comment: The reason for asking is that I'd like to compile some of my own answers to interesting questions as well as some of my own questions for my own reference. Usually I don't retain handwritten workings (this is actually in relation to Math Stackexchange) after posting the solution online.